# How do I add multiple xlink namespaces with attributes to an XML tag using lxml in Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to modify an XML document that contains the following code:

```
<draw:image>
<office:binary-data> *Some Binary Data Here* </office:binary-data>
</draw:image>
```

to the following:

```
<draw:image
 xlink:href="Pictures/1000000000000132000001C1B172F5629754D00D.jpg"
 xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad"/>
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this with the help of lxml in Python?

Comment: Are you removing tags also?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not sure what you mean. In simple words, I am trying to replace the former code with the latter.

Comment: Do you mean    `node.set("xlink:href",  "Pictures/1000000000000132000001C1B172F5629754D00D.jpg")` etc..?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I think that's it. So `draw:image.set("xlink:href"..)` etc. should do it?

Comment: You would find all your `draw:image` nodes then set the attributes in each as above, the changes will be reflected in your xml

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Okay, thank you so much :)